# How to split non-contiguous feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile with a feature that is non-contiguous. I want to split the areas on the left from the area on the right. However, QGIS's Split Features tool requires you to draw a line over the feature. When I draw a line between the two areas of this feature, it doesn't do anything.

How should I split this feature?

Here's a screen shot. The feature I want to split is in yellow.

[image: qgis screen shot]

Comment: From version 2.4 and above, there is a new tool called split parts that can solve this problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but I can't find out how.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could try **Multipart to Single Parts** in the Vector toolset, which should split what you have there, a multipolyon, into its constituent polygons, from where you should be able to delete the polygons you need to.

You can always recombine them later if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

It appeared that the multipart-to-singlepart tool wanted to bust apart all the multipart features in my layer, and create a new shapefile. This seemed overkill.

Instead I just copy/pasted the desired feature. Then I moved the copy, so as not to overlap, deleted the extra parts from both the original and the copy, and moved the copy back to its proper location.

So:
- edit layer
- select feature
- copy feature
- paste feature
- move feature (the copy)
- select original
- delete part (from original, as necessary)
- select copy
- delete part (from the copy, as necessary)
- move feature (the copy) back to original location

Comment: That's a bit cumbersome approach. QGIS has now a few tools to split multipart features, like [Multipart split  plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/), [digitizing tools plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DigitizingTools/) and split parts core function in the advanced digitizing toolbar (version 2.4 and above).

Comment: I'm now using 3.14 and the Split parts tool doesn't work on separated multiparts, although the delete parts tool does.  So I used a variation of user34450's  workaround.  I copied and pasted the multipart but didn't move, then clicked on and used the delete parts on one of the parts and then on the other.