# QGIS Dissolve/merge features that overlap

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, dissolve, union

I have a vector layer that I created through classifying an image, isolating a specific class (raster calculator), polygonize, and then created a buffer. I am trying to merge/dissolve/union the polygons that are either touching or overlapping. I've tried dissolving and technically it works, but I am only left with one polygon and I need each one for a total count.

Any Suggestions?

**Input**
[image]

**Input Attribute Table**
[image]

**Desired Output**
[image]

**Output Attribute Table. Need each polygon shown and not merged as one. So it should look like image 2, but will less features.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multi-part polygon. You want to split it into individual polygons. You can do this with Multipart to Single Parts in the Vector toolset. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23377/how-to-split-non-contiguous-feature-in-qgis) for more details.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Learn something new every day!